# XLOOKUP choosing column to seach within

Tags: excel, formula, xlookup

I am fairly new to Excel,
using `XLOOKUP(what to search, where to search range, results range)`
My question is related to the "range", I didn't find an answer to it..

I always see people using specific range to search, for example:`E4:E8`

Isn't it better to Serach in all the `E` column(E:E)?

XLOOKUP(F4, E4:E8, G4:G8)
Why not
XLOOKUP(F4, E:E, G:G)

- it's related to all formulas..
- I am clicking a cell outside of the column that I am searching it..

Comment: It's a matter of performance. Imagine 1048576 rows in Microsoft's 365 to search for a particular value ***or*** just 5...

Comment: got it! so why not choosing only 2 cells?